# Невозможно получить знак "Прокурор"

Tags: дефект, знаки, репутация

Я полтора года как честный гражданин помечал плохие вопросы тревогой, и сейчас у меня 400 из нужных 500 тревог для знака ***Прокурор***. Однако по достижению 3000 очков рейтинга у меня не накапливаются новые тревоги! Вероятно это из-за того, что теперь мои тревоги автоматически переводятся в голоса за закрытие...

Можно ли как-то дополучить этот знак без понижения репутации до 3000-? Конечно, это всего лишь какая-то виртуальная сущность, но раз уж есть геймификация на этом сайте, то пусть она будет честной и продуманной, а не замораживать навечно почти готовый результат.

Возможно к правилу получения этого знака стоит добавить не только тревоги, но и голоса за закрытие (для тех, у кого 3k+), при этом чтобы первых бело не менее трёхсот, например.

Comment: Но ведь тревоги есть не только для вопросов. Плохих ответов и комментариев тоже хватает, можно на них нафармить.

Comment: [Вполне возможно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal)

Comment: @Grundy ну-с, это не доказательство, люди у которых больше 3к могли получить знак до этого. Сейчас там как раз 5 человек у которых примерно 3к и меньше.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight спасибо, как-то забыл об этом.

Comment: @AivanF. могу привести в пример себя: знак был вручен 4 июня 2017, на это время у меня было больше 3к

Comment: @Grundy понял, спасибо (:

Comment: Ну не знаю, я вот буквально недавно получил данный знак, все вроде ок, но у меня репутация ниже в пополам от вашей.

Comment: @VladSpirin у Вас репутации меньше 3 тыс баллов, мой вопрос про ситуацию, когда больше и имеется доступ к голосам за закрытие вопросов. При этом тревоги на вопросы автоматически становятся голосами за закрытие и не учитываются в данном значке.

Comment: Я понял, я лишь написал, что сам процесс вручения знака работает, а уже в вашей ситуации думаю модераторы разберутся если что и все будет ок, награда достанется победителю :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Однако по достижению 3000 очков рейтинга у меня не накапливаются новые тревоги!

Вероятно дело в том, что тревоги и голоса за закрытие - это не одно и то же.
Даже если ты ставишь голос за закрытие через меню тревог, он тревогой не является.

[image: скриншот тревог]

Но если выбрать там закрытие, то будет

[image: скриншот голосов]

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Вот как раз с этим я и парился, что вроде бы пользуешься меню тревог, а ставится именно голос за закрытие.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему здесь сыграл роль не совсем корректный перевод описания знака.

Если перейти к [английской версии](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal) описание следующее:

> Raise 500 helpful flags.

> Оставить 500 *полезных* флагов

---

То есть, нет ограничения на что именно нужно ставить флаг, в нашем переводе - отправлять тревогу.